# Disable specific game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm making a coin system. When a player collides with trigger collider, i want it to disable only the object it collided with.

this.SetActive(false);
Finding object by name

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Coin")
    {
        this.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

/

Answer (score 2):

You were very close with your original solution, but you may be misunderstanding what is actually happening here. So I've documented my solution to show the difference.

```
/* The following script is called when a Rigidbody detects a collider that is
 * is set to be a trigger. It then passes that collider as a parameter, to this 
 * function.
 */
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
{ 
    // So here we have the other / coin collider

    // If the gameObject that the collider belongs to has a tag of coin
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin")) 
    {
        // Set the gameObject that the collider belongs to as SetActive(false)
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false); 
    }
}
```

If you want the coin to be removed from the scene, because you don't expect it to ever be reactivated, then you can amend this code to the following:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
{                     
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
    {  
        // Removes the coin from your scene instead            
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) instead of comparing `string`s using `==`. `CompareTag` is slightly faster and it also makes sure there provided `tag` actually exists otherwise throwing errors which makes debugging easier and your code more secure

Comment: @derHugo I'll take your word for it, amended now

Comment: the performance aspect is [quite small](https://caolam.com/unity-tips-use-comparetag-instead-of-string-equals) actually .. but it exists ;) For me it is more the debugging aspect that matters